# How to modify rows while iterating through them

Tags: sql, go, sqlite

I have a loop iterating through a table that looks similar to this (error handling simplified for increased readability):

```
for rows.Next() {
    var (
        id          int
        field2      int
        field1      int
    )
    err = rows.Scan(&id, &field1, &field2)
    chk(err)
    field1 += someFunc()
    field2 += someOtherFunc()
    err = db.Exec(`UPDATE table SET field1 = ?, field2 = ? WHERE id = ?`, field1, field2, id)
    chk(err)
}
```

As you can see, I want to scan the fields of each row, modify them in some way and them update the database. The values returned by `someFunc` and `someOtherFunc` are different for each row and impossible to determine from the values of its fields alone.

This piece of code doesn't work, because the database is locked until `rows` are closed (I'm using [mattn's go-sqlite3 driver](http://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3)). Additionally, it's not efficient, because the database needs to perform a query each time a row is updated. I know that I could use `db.Prepare` and then perform all of the queries once I'm done iterating, but that would consume unnecessary amounts of memory and would not alleviate the efficiency problem. 
I've done some reading and it seems like cursors provide the functionality I'm looking for (I'm not an SQL expert) and the flavor of SQL I'm using (SQLite3) supports them, but `database/sql` does not seem to.

Is there any natural way in `database/sql` to update rows while iterating through them?

Comment: Cursors are only for reading. And you must no change a table that you are reading with a cursor.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but this -> "the database is locked until `rows` are closed" sounds wrong... Is that true? Can you point me to some documentation that specifically mentions that? Or is that how the sql driver you are using behaves and what driver are you using?

Comment: @mkopriva I edited the question to include the driver. The database is indeed locked until I close `rows`. It may as well be driver-specific behavior, nothing in the documentation of `database/sql` states that it should behave this way, but nothing says it's not permitted either. I never claimed that this behavior is universal. However, I looked at my driver's documentation and it seems there's nothing about this behavior there as well.

Comment: Fair enough. Does your code by any chance run inside a transaction? I remember having a similar issue with postgres, but to fix it all I needed to do is to use a separate tx (or connection? i don't recall exactly) inside the loop. So basically I would have two connections or something, one would be used for selecting the rows and the other one for updating the table.

Comment: @mkopriva No, the code is not running inside a transaction. I have transactions in other parts of my program, but the problem occurs even on execution paths that don't make any use of them and they have been committed by the time this loop runs anyway. As for a separate connection, I'll see about that, but this kind of approach seems cumbersome to me.

Comment: It's still the same with another connection. By the way, if I close `rows` before the first update, the update succeeds, so I know with certainty that it's `rows` causing this.

Comment: I see... maybe you've already seen this (https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/issues/274) but other people seem to be having a similar issue and if the cause is the same for both issues you might be out of luck with this driver...

Comment: @mkopriva Yeah, it seems to be the driver that's causing this. The most elegant working solution that I've found for now seems to be starting a transaction before the loop, using it for `Exec` calls and committing it once the loop is finished. This probably still uses far more memory than it should, but at least it looks better in code. I think I'll consider switching to a different driver in a near future.

Answer (score 0):

You should execute your SELECTs & UPDATEs against a transaction, not a handle. I've stumbled with it in one of my projects, and now have a code like this:

```
tx, err := dbh.Begin()
...
rows1, err := tx.Query("SELECT id, data FROM cache")
...
for rows1.Next() {
...
   tx.Exec("DELETE FROM cache WHERE id = ?", id)
...
}
tx.Commit()
```

And no more errors about a locked database.